# Is there analytical solution for this problem?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to find a closed form for the following probability: 
P(y-x<1) given that y and x have gaussian distribution with different mean and variance for (y>0) and (x>-1). I was able to find the distribution of (z=y-z) and it was in the following form: 
$f_z=const.*e^{\frac{z}{d}}e^{\frac{-z^{2}}{2d}}[erf(\frac{a z}{b}+\tfrac{a}{c})+1]$
where a,b,c & d are constants related to the mean and variance of x & y but I couldn't solve the integral over this distribution to find the probability.

Comment: If y and -x are independent normal variables, then z = y - x has also a gaussian distribution, of which we know the mean and the variance directly. Then, just use the CDF of z.

Comment: @Harry49 I know this rule but the values of x>-1 and y>0 (not from -inf to inf). So, is this rule still valid?

Comment: Gaussian variables have values all over $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe, you are considering a restriction. Alternatively, you may want to compute the probability P(y-x<1 and y>0 and x>-1), which is the intersection of three events.

Comment: @Harry49 yes, I want to find P(y-x<1&y>0&x>-1). Is there an analytical solution for it?

Comment: Ok. Then, i would suggest to write it P(0<y<x+1 and x+1>0), and rewrite it P(0<y<x+1, x+1>0) P(x+1>0) [Bayes theorem]. The left term is computed using the joint distribution of (x,y), which pdf is the product of the pdfs of x and y, by virtue of independence. The right term involves the cdf of x.